# Swagger Generates docs for the classes in jar

Tags: rest, jar, annotations, war, swagger

New to swagger :

I have a web application which combines multiple modules jars into a single war file. Now I want to be able to generate swagger docs for those modules classes (jars) as well. how do I do it?

Comment: Either the question is missing some crucial details, or you simply haven't read the numerous docs out there on how to integrate Swagger with your application.